# Importing .jar file into eclipse for editing

Tags: eclipse, jar, project

How do I import a .jar file (containing a java project) into eclipse so that I can edit the classes inside, add classes, ect.. just like a project that had been created inside eclipse?

(background story): The charger for my laptop broke and I didn't realize it until the battery was almost dead.  During the 20 remaining minutes of battery life I tried to save a project I have been working on for 6 months by exporting it as a .jar and emailing it to myself.  I now have a new computer and want to get working on my project again, but I don't know how to do that with my .jar file.  I've tried importing it as an external library, and this allows me to run the project, but I can't seem to edit the classes this way (eclipse says it needs a source?).

I'm not sure if this info helps, but here's some more about the project:

The .jar contains: a dozen .class files, 1 .project file, 1 .classpath file, 1 .txt file (used by the program to write/read to), a bunch of image files (used by the program for graphics)

The project was made in JRE 1.8

Comment: .class files contain the compiled byte code of the classes, not the Java source code which is in files with the .java extension. There are some 'decompilers' which will try and reconstruct the source for the .class file but the result won't be as good as the original source.

Comment: Thanks this worked!  It wasn't too great at reconstructing switches, but everything else looks goods!